# Fill input box and choose first dropdown value in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to access a webpage that has only one input box, fill it with a string and then select the first dropdown option that comes from it. The reason to select the first option is because it does not work unless you pick it, even if the text contains exactly the same as the dropdown option.

I have managed to do something like this for this page like this:
http://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/lumis/lum-ajustes-do-pregao-ptBR.asp

```
    #request
    with requests.Session() as s:
        esquema = {'dData1': d_0_}
        url_post = 'http://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/lumis/lum-ajustes-do-pregao-ptBR.asp'


        r_1 = s.post(url_post, data=esquema)
        tabela_ajuste = pd.read_html(r_1.content,thousands='.', decimal=',')
        tabela_ajuste = tabela_ajuste[0].dropna(axis=0, thresh=4).fillna(method='ffill')
```

I would like do adapt that for this page: https://www.precodogas.com.br/fazer-pedido-ads.php

Where I would fill the input with text `Rua Joaquim Floriano 733, Itaim Bibi, São Paulo, 04534-012, BRA` and select the first option then scrape the resulting page to get `69,99` as a result.

I wonder how I would scrape the page because the URL bar does not change.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try post the url that is being used to get the data.
The return will be in a JSON format

I used the following url

```
url ='https://www.precodogas.com.br/include/lista_revenda.php?acao=listar&pagenum=0&pagesize=21&filtervalue0=1&filteroperator0=0&filtercondition0=EQUAL&filterdatafield0=produto&filterscount=1&sortdatafield=valor&sortorder=asc'
```

And I used the following code to get the response

```
import requests
import json
esquema = {
       'log_bairro':'Itaim Bibi',
       'log_cep':'04534-012',
       'log_cidade':'São Paulo',
       'log_estado':'SP',
       'log_rua':'Rua Joaquim Floriano',
       'posLat':-23.585270016261035,
       'posLong':-46.676920031512594
}
response = requests.post(url,data=esquema)
data = json.loads(response.content)
```

If you print the value of data, you get the following

```
{
'resultado': '1',
'TotalRows': '1',
'rua': 'Rua Joaquim Floriano',
'Rows': [{
    'media': '4',
    'idproduto': '7781',
    'idrevendedor': '2414',
    'brinde': '',
    'maxdist': '5.6',
    'revendedor': 'CASA DO GÁS PERDIZES',
    'endereco': 'Rua Bragança, 48 - Pacaembu',
    'fabricante': 'Liquigás',
    'logomarca': 'liquigas.jpg',
    'valor': '69,99',
    'valorportaria': '69,99',
    'produto': 'Gás de Cozinha',
    'qtdparcela': '0',
    'peso': '13',
    'destaque': None,
    'distance': '5,1',
    'formaspg': [{
        'id': '1',
        'descricao': 'Dinheiro',
        'icon': 'fa-money'
    }, {
        'id': '2',
        'descricao': 'Cartão débito ou crédito',
        'icon': 'fa-credit-card'
    }, {
        'id': '3',
        'descricao': 'Cartão débito ou crédito',
        'icon': 'fa-credit-card-alt'
    }],
    'funcionamento': [{
        'id': '',
        'hrinicio': '08:30',
        'hrfim': '19:30',
        'descricao': 'Segunda a Sexta'
    }, {
        'id': '',
        'hrinicio': '08:30',
        'hrfim': '19:00',
        'descricao': 'Sábado'
    }, {
        'id': '',
        'hrinicio': '08:30',
        'hrfim': '13:30',
        'descricao': 'Domingo'
    }],
    'aberto': '1',
    'bgcolor': '#008651',
    'txtcolor': '#FFF'
}]
```

}

Comment: Eduardo, thank you so much. How do you get the url?

Comment: I used the postman app with the postman interceptor extension for chrome.

Comment: Thanks, Eduardo. It worked great and I managed to use Postman as well.

Comment: Cool!! I am glad to help. Happy Coding!